# 10001st Prime - Project Euler

Tags: c#, math

So I'm doing the 7th Project Euler problem, and I'm not sure why this code isn't working, it seems to be okay so small numbers, I've tested 1-10 and it's fine, but doesn't return the correct answer at 10001 - returns 104745.

And yes, I know it's inefficient.

```
private void eulerSeven(int num)
    {
        // Start the Prime count at 3, with 2 already counted. 
        int primecount = 1, counter = 3;

        //While num of primes counted < the nth prime
        while (primecount < num)
        {                
            bool isPrime = true;
            //check every number from 2 -> the current number we're checking
            for (int i = 2; i < counter; i++)
            {
                if (counter%i == 0)
                {
                    //if divisible, not a prime
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isPrime) //If is a prime, increment counter
            {   primecount++; }
            // Go to next number (only checking odds)
            counter += 2;
        }

        //output nth prime
       Console.WriteLine(counter);
    }
```

Comment: Show your code for `//output nth prime`

Comment: Console.WriteLine(counter);

Comment: should be `counter - 2`

Comment: Oh my god I'm an idiot. Thanks,

Comment: This is a good time to learn debugging skills. You can track down issues like this by using a source level debugger in Visual Studio or adding more Console.WriteLine() calls to see what the value of each variable is.

Comment: " I've tested 1-10 and it's fine" seem to be very suspicious too... Writing UnitTest is very good idea...

Comment: Not sure what was going on with the small tests. But I did use the VS debugger @Code-Apprentice, I just either didn't take it all the way through the code (Just checked it was iterating correctly and incrementing) or didn't notice when it incremented just before outputting the answer. One day I'll git gud at debugging

Comment: Please accept an answer that really answer your question to flag this as "solved". You can write an answer too and accept that. But never change the title with a "solved" or anything like that word - that is not SO style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @lanorkin, the problem was:

> should be `counter - 2`

but also, I would like to suggest a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/124644/project-euler-7-10001st-prime, so this code should do the same, but very very fast (5ms on my machine):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Console.WriteLine(CalculateEulerSeven(10001)); // should be 104745
    stopwatch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Time to calculate in milliseconds : {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static int CalculateEulerSeven(int num)
{
    int primecount = 1, counter = 3;

    while (primecount < num)
    {
        bool isPrime = IsPrime(counter);

        if (isPrime) primecount++;
        counter += 2;
    }

    return counter;
}

static bool IsPrime(int value)
{
    if (value < 2) { return false; }
    if (value % 2 == 0) { return value == 2; }
    if (value % 3 == 0) { return value == 3; }
    if (value % 5 == 0) { return value == 5; }
    if (value == 7) { return true; }

    for (int divisor = 7; divisor * divisor <= value; divisor += 30)
    {
        if (value % divisor == 0) { return false; }
        if (value % (divisor + 4) == 0) { return false; }
        if (value % (divisor + 6) == 0) { return false; }
        if (value % (divisor + 10) == 0) { return false; }
        if (value % (divisor + 12) == 0) { return false; }
        if (value % (divisor + 16) == 0) { return false; }
        if (value % (divisor + 22) == 0) { return false; }
        if (value % (divisor + 24) == 0) { return false; }
    }

    return true;
}
```